# How to remove graphic card drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, uninstall, intel-graphics

I'm completely new at linux so i need some help please.
I just bought a NVIDIA Quadro k 600 graphic card and i need to install it in my computer which has instead an Intel Q45/Q43. The quick installation guide manual tells me to remove the old graphic drivers before i actually substitute the new NVIDIA card.

When i type `lshw -c video` in the terminal i get:

```
  *-display:0               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphic Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 03
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:49 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:1230(size=8)

  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED              
   description: Display controller
   product: 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphic Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2.1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list 
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f0400000-f04fffff
```

So my questions are:
- how do i remove the drivers (which i suppose it is i915)?
- is there anything else i should do before i go ahead and substitute the old graphic card with the new one?
- am i missing anything important or should i be just fine?

I hope you understood my question and can give me some help with this problem.

Comment: Did you specifically install anything for the old card? In theory, you do not need to do anything but swap video cards. With the new card you can try the open source drier and if that fails the closed source driver. Post back if you are having an actual problem.